# Encoding problems while displaying file content in <pre> tag

Tags: html, encoding, pre

So here is my problem. I have files that I display in  tags. However, when the file contains special caracters like 'é', 'à' ... they are not prompted properly and are replaced by '?' . Retyping the caracters and saving the file in the web app solve the problem but it's not very user-friendly.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

**EDIT**

Those caracters are in sh and conf files. Those files are written by ops and thus, i'd like to find a solution not implying having them type caracters with html codes. The pages are all using UTF-8 encoding already.

Answer (score 0):

Because the browser cannot interpret these symbols in your HTML source file directly they have to use special predefined key values to identify what symbols you want to display. If you follow this link i'm sure you will find the code for all the symbols you are looking for : http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html

Otherwise you will continue to have the '?'.